# Dart - Circular dependency while initializing static field

Tags: dart, circular-dependency

I'm new to dart and just encountered an issue which I don't understand yet.
I wrote this class:

```
class Currency {
    final String symbol;
    final String name;

    // constants for all available Currencies
    static const Currency EURO = const Currency._euro();
    static const Currency POUND = const Currency._pound();
    static const Currency DOLLAR = const Currency._dollar();

    // All available currencies as a list
    static const List<Currency> CURRENCIES = const [
        EURO,
        POUND,
        DOLLAR,
    ];

    // Default constructor
    Currency(this.symbol, this.name);

    // Named constructors
    const Currency._euro() : this('€', 'Euro');

    const Currency._pound() : this('£', 'British Pound');

    const Currency._dollar() : this('\$', 'US Dollar');

    // toString()
    @override
    String toString() => '$symbol ($name)';
}
```

When using this class, for example with the statement below I get a *"Circular dependency while initializing static field"*-error.

```
Currency currency = Currency.EURO;
```

Could anyone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: What Dart version are you using? Is this in DDC, dart2js, console app, Flutter?

Comment: I'm using Flutter (Version 0.1.5) with Dart (version 2.0.0-dev.28.0.flutter-0b4f01f759).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error, but a `const` was missing before the constructor you redirect others to

```
const Currency(this.symbol, this.name);
```

Comment: That did indeed solve the problem. Could you explain to me why this is?

Comment: `const Currency._euro();` demands `const` and that only works with `const` constructors. If you forward to another constructor that also must be const. Not sure if that is what you asked for.

Comment: I suppose what I'm asking is why omitting that one `const` would result in in *circular dependency*. Could this have anything to do with lazy initialization of constants?

Comment: It could, not sure, but I wasn't able to reproduce your error. Probably because I use a newer Dart version (2.0.0-dev.24.0)